# how to select the certain properties from object?

Tags: javascript

please help solve the problem.

i have follow object:

```
  defaults = {
    title: undefined,
    yMax: undefined,
    yMin: undefined,
    yPeriod: undefined,
    xMax: undefined,
    xMin: undefined,
    xPeriod: undefined,
    dots: {}
  }
```

I need to get an array of properties that are of type "not object".

i.e. i need get follow:

```
[title, yMax, yMin, yPeriod, xMax, xMin, xPeriod]
```

Comment: You want their names? Or their values? It's unclear from the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check type of each property with `typeof`

```js
var defaults = {
   title: undefined,
   yMax: undefined,
   yMin: undefined,
   yPeriod: undefined,
   xMax: undefined,
   xMin: undefined,
   xPeriod: undefined,
   dots: {}
 }

 var a = [];
 for (prop in defaults) {
   if (typeof defaults[prop] != 'object') a.push(prop);
 }

 console.log(a);
```

Comment: Take in mind that an Array is considered an object using typeof operator.

Answer (score 1):

Just a single line in ES6 with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var defaults = { title: undefined, yMax: undefined, yMin: undefined, yPeriod: undefined, xMax: undefined, xMin: undefined, xPeriod: undefined, dots: {} },
    keys = Object.keys(defaults).filter(a => typeof defaults[a] !== 'object');

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(keys, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Or is ES5 a single line, too

```js
var defaults = { title: undefined, yMax: undefined, yMin: undefined, yPeriod: undefined, xMax: undefined, xMin: undefined, xPeriod: undefined, dots: {} },
    keys = Object.keys(defaults).filter(function (a) { return typeof defaults[a] !== 'object'; });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(keys, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this all functional-style, you could combine [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
var arr = Object.keys(defaults).filter(function(key) {
  return typeof defaults[key] !== 'object';
}).map(function(key) {
  return defaults[key];
});
```

Or writing this same stuff using ES6:

```
let arr = Object.keys(default)
  .filter(key => typeof defaults[key] !== 'object')
  .map(key => defaults[key]);
```

This will get you the values of everything in defaults which is not an object (this means arrays will also be excluded). If you only want the keys, just remove the `map` function.